# Rails Devise - prevent redirect to log in from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want users to access the home page whether they're authenticated or not. Though, whenever the root url is visited, the user is immediately redirected to /users/sign_in. How do I disable this?

### `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'
  devise_for :users

end
```

### `home_controller.rb`

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
  
  def index
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

With Devise is usually better to  require authentication by default and then add exceptions with `skip_before_action`:

```erb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
 
  def index
  end
end
```

This avoids the risk of leaving security holes just by programmer omission.

Comment: Hmm ... I added these lines and my app still redirects to sign_in from the root.
\
`Processing by HomeController#index as HTML`
\
... some stuff ...
\
then `Started GET "/users/sign_in"`

Comment: This isn't going to be something that actually can be replicated. And this is how you skip the authentication callback. Are you sure you're actually running the correct code and that its not just a simple programmer error?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. My ApplicationController and HomeController look identical to what you posted. My routes haven't changed from the original post. I can't seem to find any other resource on the internet for why this is...hence my frustration lol.

Comment: You're really goinng have to scale off the pieces here and create a minimal example that replicates the behavior. If you have a public repo I can take a look.

Comment: Not entirely sure how I fixed this...honestly. But I have an idea. Something funky was going on with the way I was passing props to my React front end. I had set a button with onClick = {location.href = this.props.sign_in_path}. Once I set onClick to href, problem was fixed. Silly issue, but thanks for the help!